# Do I really have to move my Symfony project to /var/www directory?

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I am following this article in creating my symfony project :

[Install Symfony3 with nginx in ubuntu 14.04](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-symfony-3-framework-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04/)

It says in here that after creating my symfony project :

```
symfony new project_name
```

I have to move my project to directory /var/www

```
mv /project_name /var/www/your-domain.com
```

But my project is inside a repository in github which cant be moved. How do I proceed? I'm using nginx by the way

Thanks

Comment: Nah.  What you want to do is to setup a nginx server block which points to your project web directory.  Takes a few steps.  This might help: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Not sure what github has to do with this. You don't have to move it, but you'd need to make sure your php-fpm and nginx config are updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are installing it for ***development*** only (say, on your laptop), you ***don't*** need a webserver like nginx. You can use the built-in webserver. In your project root execute:

`php bin/console server:start`

By default the server listens on http://localhost:8000

If you are installing it on a dedicated server install nginx and create this file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` name it `yoursite`. You only have to serve the `web` directory of your project.

```
server {
    server_name yoursite.com;
    root /home/your_user/path/to/your/project/web;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }
    # DEV
    # This rule should only be placed on your development environment
    # In production, don't include this and don't deploy app_dev.php or config.php
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }
    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        # internal;
    }
 # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
    location ~ \.php$ {
      return 404;
    }
```

Symlink the file to the `sites-enabled` directory.

`sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/yoursite /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/yoursite`.

Remove the `default` configuration from the `sites-enabled` directory. Restart nginx.

[See super speed symfony](https://gnugat.github.io/2016/04/20/super-speed-sf-nginx.html)

You may have to set permissions for cache, log and upload directories. See the [Symfony Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html)

Comment: Yes, this is the answer I was looking for, the symfony doc shows this in their nginx guide but it doesnt say what file is this or where its located. I ended up editing my nginx.conf

Comment: Nice. The file is an almost straight copy of one of my setups.